# Netlogo: converting reporter to anonymous procedure

Tags: netlogo

I'm having trouble converting an older model to Netlogo 6. Specifically, I have two reporters process lists that I can't get to work correctly with the new syntax. Both incorporate the old ?2 ?1 syntax used in V5.0 and below. I would appreciate any assistance. Here is the code

```
to-report util-partial-sums [#lst]                                                                  
  set #lst (fput [0] #lst)  
  report butfirst reduce [lput (?2 + last ?1) ?1] #lst 
end


to-report util-compare-adjacent-pairs-in-list [randnum specieslist]

let post 0
let list1 (butlast specieslist)                                                                      
let list2 (butfirst specieslist)                                                                      

ifelse randnum <= first specieslist [set post 0]                                                     
  [ifelse randnum > last specieslist [set post position (last specieslist) specieslist]              
    [
       (foreach list1 list2 [
          if randnum > ?1 and randnum <= ?2 [set post ((position ? specieslist) + 1)]])              
    ]
  ]
report post
end
```

Comment: could you please provide some test data and the expected result for that data?

Comment: I think the issue is understanding how to fix the syntax, rather than any semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous procedures now require you to explicitly define parameters (in-line), rather than  use pre-defined 1st/2nd.

That being said:

```
[lput (?2 + last ?1) ?1]
```

should be mapped to

```
[[x y] -> lput (y + last x) x]
```

The same issue occurs within the for loop.

This is particularly useful:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures

Anonymous procedure takes more than one input
nothing

> (foreach xs ys [ [ x y ] -> setx x + y ])
>
> (map [ [ x y ] -> x mod round y ] xs ys)